# Loading tensorflow checkpoint by skipping the head layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am using a model (SimCLR) to learn representations from images. While pre-training, the model was trained against a single dummy label. Now I want to fine-tune the model with 8-class data.
While loading the pre-trained model checkpoint to the yet to be fine-tuned model with 8-class head I am encountering a ValueError.

```
ValueError: Tensor's shape (2048, 1) is not compatible with supplied shape [2048, 8]
```

Is there a solution to exclude the last head layer weights before loading to the checkpoint for fine-tuning the model?

---

#### System information

- **TensorFlow version**: 2.5.0
- **Python version**: 3.7.3

Answer (score 1):

Well, to have your pre-trained model be able to successfully deal with your new inputs, they would need to be in the exact same shape as the old input it expects (from the old 1D model). To have your 8-class data work with this model, you need to change the model itself to handle the inputs of 8 classes. This will likely require you to edit the attributes of the model itself, and without a visual of the code it is hard to say exactly where you need to make that change.

Comment: I feed the same size input images both the times. The error is coming from the final classification head.